# Priority order of routes when both Express and React Router routes coexist

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, react-router

I created a project that contains a React frontend and a Node.js backend. directory structure as follows:

```
├── server
│   └── server.js
├── react_client
│   ├── index.js
│   └── App.js
```

In package.js:

```
……
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
……
    "express": "^4.18.2",
……
```

In sever.js, I set routes:

```
app = express()

app.get("/api/login", loginFunction)

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../react_client/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`)
})
```

In App.js, I also set routes:

```
<Route path={'/'} element={}/>

<Route path={'/dashboard'} element={}/>

<Route path="*" element={
    <Notfound/>
}/>
```

There is a phenomenon that i can't understand. After I create a page like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Home=()=>{
  return <Link to='/api/login'>
          login button</Link>
}
```

I click the Link Label, it will show the Notfound, which defined in App.js file.
If I refresh this page, will show the function defined in sever.js file, which I want to show.

Then I edit the page like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const Home=()=>{
  const refreshPage = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload(false);
      }, 300)
  }

  return <Link to='/api/login' onClick={refreshPage}>
          login button</Link>
}
```

It seems to work, but the solution is very inelegant in core, need wait for a while.

In my previous cognition, priority order of Express routes is higher than React Router routes.

Why will it will show the Notfound page, that Express routes fail when I use Link label?

Is that related with Link label?

Is there some better solution to show sever.js file route?

Thanks for you reading.

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't know about Express in development. So when you try to reach backend endpoints from the frontend it won't work. Take a look at [Proxying API Requests in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

I find using a `setupProxy.js` gives most control over which endpoints access your backend.

For example, in `Express` you can dedicate all "API" calls to `/api`. Then proxy all `/api` frontend requests to the `backend` /api` route handler.

**react_client/setupProxy.js**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const proxy_urls = ['/api/*'];

const target = 'http://localhost:3001'; // <--- Express server port

module.exports = function (app) {
  proxy_urls.forEach((url) => {
    app.use(url, createProxyMiddleware({ target }));
  });
};
```

Then instead of using `Link` to hit your backend, use `fetch` or a library like `axios.

`const results = await fetch('/api/login')`;

It wasn't clear in your post, but if you are for some reason trying to serve some HTML on the server through React, then you would still need to proxy requests to that end-point which uses sendFile. But it seems you are just intending to hit your backend from your React app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Sorry I didn't make it clear in my post about the reason I want redirect to backend. I use a third party function that will redirect the /api/login to another url. So it is not easy to fetch it.
Your answer works for a while, but it will cause issue that I find no way to fix: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12035.
Now I use window.location.href = 'api/login', it works.
Thank you again, Although my account don't have upvote function now.